# Generic props : why are these types incompatible?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two React components with props taking a generic parameter `TVariables`. These props have the following fields : `variables` of type `TVariables` and `setVariables` of type `(vars: TVariables) => void`.

When I use my component like this :

```js
const [variables, setVariables] = useState({ ...someProperties })

<A variables={variables} setVariables={setVariables}/>
```

I would expect component `A` to infer `TVariables`, and so both props to work. But I have an incompatibility error when setting `setVariables`.

This description is pretty obscure and the typescript error report is even more, so I created a minimalist codesandbox demo :

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-dust-ll39z?file=/src/App.tsx)

Why do I have these errors, and how could I solve them ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the type `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<TVariables>>` for `setVariables`.

Set state functions in React can passed the new value for the state variable, but can also be passed a callback function that updates the state variable. Thus the type `(variables: TVariables) => void` does not match the type of a React set state function.

Comment: Weird since I just pass a function to a more narrow function definition, which has always worked in the past for me. But indeed, it solves the codesandbox errors, but not in my actual project and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Typescript is complaining because of these 2 variables that you declared in your initial state

```js
test: "demo",
sortOrder: -1,
```

If you add those to the `ListVariables`, the error disappears:

```js
type ListVariables = {
  limit: number;
  page: number;
  test: string;
  sortOrder: number;
};
```

Comment: In my actual project, this is not possible.

Comment: Can you remove those from the initial state in the function?

Comment: Here is actually a more up to date version of the topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65201244/generic-props-why-isnt-this-type-correctly-inferred I'll close this one.