# Generic props : Why isn't this type correctly inferred?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a very simple `Demo` component with props taking a generic parameter `TVariables` :

```js
type Variables = {
  limit: number;
  page: number;
  search?: string | null;
  sort?: string | null;
  sortOrder?: number | null;
};

type Props<TVariables extends Variables> = {
  variables: TVariables;
  setVariables(variables: TVariables): void;
};

function Demo<TVariables extends Variables>(props: Props<TVariables>) {
  return null;
}
```

But then, when I try to use it in conjunction with `useState`, it doesn't infer `TVariables` correctly :

```js
function useListVariables<T>(init: T) {
  return React.useState<Omit<T, keyof Variables> & Variables>({
    search: null,
    sort: "_id",
    sortOrder: 1,
    limit: 10,
    page: 1,
    ...init
  });
}

export default function App() {
  const [variables, setVariables] = useListVariables({
    test: "demo",
    sortOrder: -1,
    limit: 4
  });

  return <Demo variables={variables} setVariables={setVariables} />;
}
```

On the second to last line, `setVariables` is underlined as an error :

```
(method) setVariables(variables: Variables): void
Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<Pick<{ test: string; sortOrder: number; limit: number; }, "test"> & Variables>>' is not assignable to type '(variables: Variables) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'variables' are incompatible.
    Type 'Variables' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<Pick<{ test: string; sortOrder: number; limit: number; }, "test"> & Variables>'.
      Type 'Variables' is not assignable to type 'Pick<{ test: string; sortOrder: number; limit: number; }, "test"> & Variables'.
        Property 'test' is missing in type 'Variables' but required in type 'Pick<{ test: string; sortOrder: number; limit: number; }, "test">'.ts(2322)
App.tsx(41, 5): 'test' is declared here.
App.tsx(17, 3): The expected type comes from property 'setVariables' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props<Variables>'
```

Here is where it gets weird. If I explicitly set the generic parameter on the component, the error disappears :

```js
// This works

<Demo<typeof variables> variables={variables} setVariables={setVariables} />
```

Also, if I rewrite the prop this way, I works too :

```js
// This works

<Demo variables={variables} setVariables={variables => setVariables(variables)} />
```

I have a Codesandbox link for you to try it yourself : [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-river-vh6wc?file=/src/App.tsx)

What is going on here and how could I solve the error without explicitly setting the generic type ? Thank you.

Comment: I think it's an interesting thing from a "here's an interesting inference puzzle" perspective, but is explicitly passing the generic type parameter really such a big deal?

Comment: @JaredSmith I want to understand that "puzzle", that's my point.

Comment: Nope, that's fair enough, which is why I didn't downvote or VTC.